# Mouse cursor is not showing in windows store game developing using monogame

Tags: xna, monogame, windows-store

I am developing a game for windows store (desktops) using monogame framework. everything else is working excellent except the Mouse cursor which is working well but not showing at time of playing game.

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
     {
        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        TouchCollection touch = TouchPanel.GetState();
        ms = Mouse.GetState();
        if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("pressedddddd");
        }


    }
```

you can see above code ... i am getting ouptut in output window "pressed" but i cant see the cursor on screen i am developing this on windows 8.1 pc and visual studio 2013 using monogame

Comment: You should try to look on google before asking questions. Simply set this.IsMouseVisible = true at initialization.

Comment: i already checked on google actually but got nothing useful . bdw yours works well. plz post it in ans

Comment: MonoGame and XNA have the same API so when you google this stuff try including xna as a keyword. for example "show mouse cursor xna" turned up loads of results.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=show+mousecursor+xna&oq=show+mousecursor+xna&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6508j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Put the below in the initialization function to make the mouse visible.

```
    this.IsMouseVisible = true;
```